# SQL: Find the number of visits of each new user in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know the `fullVisitorId, visitID, visitNumber, totals.pageviews` which all give me information about the session.

I'm trying to write an efficient query, such that I only look at new users to create the following table:

```
user | #visits | #total_pages | #pages/visit
```

Sample DB that I just came up with:

```
Row fullVisitorId   visitID                 visitNumber  page_views
1   27              15                      1            10
2   27              20                      2            15
3   27              1921                    3            5
4   654             15                      1            28 
5   575             16                      3            1
6   547             16                      1            4
```

The user column is populated with `fullVisitorId`, #visits is the number of visits.

Since I'm only interested in new users, I first wrote a query to select new users, where visit number = 1. This is

```
SELECT fullVisitorId FROM (SELECT fullVisitorId, visitID, visitNumber, page_views FROM [table] WHERE visitNumber =1) GROUP BY fullVisitorId
```

Now, this is the first column in my database, the `user` table completed.

For the second column `#visits`, I need to find the number of visits, which is simply the SUM of unique `visitIDs` that belong to the user. It should return 3 for user 27, 1 for users 654 and 547 (note that user 575 is excluded). Something like:

> SELECT * FROM (table) WHERE fullVisitorID IN (1stQuery) to remove the
>   old users (only new required) and then count the number of visits.

3rd column, would aggregate the number of pages viewed, and return (10+15+5=30) for user 27, and so on.

The last column is simply the division of #total_pages and #visits.

*Ideally, at the end I would get:*

```
user | #visits | #total_pages | #pages/visit
27     3         30             10
654    1         28             28
547    1         4              4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, COUNT(*) as NumVisits,
       SUM(PageViews) as TotalPages,
       AVG(PageViews) as AvgPages
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY fullVisitorId
HAVING MIN(VisitNumber) = 1;
```

I don't think you gain anything by making the query more complicated by filtering before the aggregation.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it seems that you are not including visitID at all

Comment: It seems I need to do a subquery where instead of [table] I have SELECT fullVisitorId, visitID, visitNumber...

Comment: @GRS . . . The information in `visitId` is encoded in `VisitNumber` and each row appears to be for a different visit.  Is that not true?  If this isn't true, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT visitId)`.

Comment: Each VisitId is unique only to the fullvisitorID, so as shown in the example table, visitors 575 and 547 have the same visitID but different userID.

Comment: Could you please explain the property MIN(VisitNumber)? Does it look only at visitors where VisitNumber=1? Or will it also look at visitors where visit number could start with 2? Since 2>1?

Comment: @GRS . . . This guarantees that the first visit is in the table, for any full visitor returned by the query.